# Creating a combined rank score using variables a, b, c, and d, (each is a score 1-100) for constituents using a platform?

Tags: importance, rating, ranks

I am tasked with creating an overall score that will be used to represent a supplier's holistic value on our site. For example, consumers of supplier's service will want to find suppliers on our site and decide which to choose among a list of options. This score should represent the holistic value so that consumers can make the best decision.

I have a list of 4 variables, which are things like Speed & Quality which we must use as inputs to the score. Each variable is a score itself from 1 to 100. Each is normally distributed but some variables have significantly more variability/spread than others (the data is more widely distributed from 1 to 100). The net impact of this difference in variability is that it is apparently easier to over/under-perform in variables with wider distributions. Currently I have approached the problem as a linear combination with varA*weightA + varB*weightB... = Overall Score.

Is this general approach acceptable statistically speaking?

My concern is that the more widely distributed variables give an unfair advantage/disadvantage to suppliers who outperform/underperform on these variables. My current solution is to weight these variables less, but it seems arbitrary and unscientific.

Comment: This problem should be familiar from secondary school when mathematics or language exams spread out people from excellent (100% was perhaps possible)  to the opposite but other exams (no names here) were such that weak students could waffle but no-one was perfect;,What anybody did about that could vary by purpose. Similarly there is no right answer here **except that** you have scope to experiment and see how much depends on weighting, say equal weights or judgment-based weights. Using outcome data to estimate weights is in principle attractive; that's regression under another name,

Comment: The technical allusions are presumably informal. A variable bounded by 1 and 100 can't be normally distributed but perhaps you mean just approximately bell-shaped. SImilarly "significantly" I guess means just "noticeably". That's small pedantry except that marked non-normality (e.g. skewness or fat tails) wouldn't be surprising to me: perhaps a few firms really are very good or very bad (the latter being about to go out of business?).

Comment: @NickCox Thank you. Your comments are helpful validation. 

Correct - the curves are bell shapes, and true, they don't go on to infinity.